# Bar chart: symbolic x cords showing multiple times

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a bar chart like this

[image]

There are suposed to be 4 x coords (50k, 150k, 250k, 350k) and they are being multiplied.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    width = \textwidth,
    ybar,
    ylabel=Number of vehicles sold,
    xlabel=Price,
    symbolic x coords = {50k, 150k, 250k, 350k},
    ]
\addplot[color = red!50]
    coordinates {(50k,1) (150k,5)(250k,10) (350k,20)};

\addplot[fill = blue!50]
    coordinates {(50k,30) (150k,10) (250k,0) (350k,0)};

\addplot[fill = green!50]
    coordinates {(50k,2) (150k,10) (250k, 25) (350k,5)};
  
\legend{Mercedes,Dacia,VW}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.